# Using keyboard attached to PC or Mac as Bluetooth keyboard for iPad?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, ipad

I would like to use my computer keyboard (USB) as a Bluetooth keyboard for my iPad, while I am using it with my computer.  I was hoping their was an "app for that" that I could run on either Mac or Windows.  I imagine how it would work:  It would have to emulate a Bluetooth keyboard, and be able to pair with the iPad.  Then, when you give focus to this app, it transmits keystrokes from your built-in keyboard out over the Bluetooth connection.  Seems simple, but I can't seem to find anything definitive on Google.

Has anybody done this?  I figure this is cheaper that buying a [Apple iPad Keyboard Dock](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC533LL/A) or a [Apple Wireless Keyboard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184LL/A) from the Apple Store.  Also, it's one less item on my desk, which gets cluttered enough with one keyboard.

Comment: So you want your PC to act as a bluetooth keyboard to your iPad? Bluetooth keyboards are quite cheap these days, so I'd wager that few people would go to the trouble to implement something as exotic as you are proposing instead of just buying a bluetooth keyboard. They say however, that the camera connection kit will let you use any USB keyboard with the iPad. Even that kit will be similarly expensive as a bluetooth keyboard though.

Comment: Good comment, it's more about the space and the ability than the cost.

Comment: Yes, we want to do this over wifi rather than through any device including the Wormhole ($70 device which allows keyboard mouse shared interface over OSX)

Comment: I'm looking for something like this on Windows. Did you ever find anything?

Comment: @newenglander https://github.com/debauchee/barrier

Answer (score 1):

I hear that the [iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A) will also let you plug in a USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use any wireless bluetooth keyboard on ipad.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify, I want to use the keyboard though the computer, and not directly with the iPad (it's not Bluetooth).

Answer (score 0):

There is [Type2Phone](https://www.houdah.com/type2Phone/). I use it and it is perfect, but it is not for free and it's only for Mac.

Comment: Could you explain why you choose this option over the others available? Please see [How to recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Answer (score 0):

[Across](https://www.acrosscenter.com/) sounds like it does what you want.

> Bluetooth Keyboard/Mouse Emulator: across makes a Bluetooth equipped
> PC or Mac work as a standard Bluetooth keyboard/mouse combo. Thus, you
> can seamlessly/wirelessly control all your smart devices including
> computer, smartphone and tablet PC with the computer’s keyboard