# Using Laptop Keyboard for my iPad

Tags: keyboard, window, ipad

I am a university student who takes notes on an iPad which mainly consist of math equations. However, sometimes I want to write some quick explanations on a keyboard. I feel like buying a Bluetooth keyboard for this (like suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/158221/using-keyboard-attached-to-pc-or-mac-as-bluetooth-keyboard-for-ipad)) is a bit overkill as I always also have my Laptop with me.

I have tried searching the web, but have yet to find a good solution as most of the advice threads are just about using an iPad as a second monitor.

Thanks

Comment: Questions about iOS devices are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: A laptop keyboard is wired to the mainboard with a ribbon cable. No separate output. What you want will not work.

Comment: There are various remote access solutions for iPad that may or may not work for this specific use case. I suggest getting an Apple Pencil instead.

Comment: this would be a better fit for https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Apple's [Universal Control](https://support.apple.com/HT212757)?

It does precisely that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1152757)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).